# How to add a splash image in Grub2?

Tags: grub2, plymouth

How do I add a splash image in Grub2 on Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 2):

There are two pages I have found directly relates to Ubuntu that can assist you with this task.

The first is from [Community ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays#Installing_Splash_Images), the second is from [UbuntuGuide.org](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aQuantal#Grub2_background_image.2C_colors.2C_fonts)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-change-grub2-background-image.html There a good explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.